# Java JDK location error while running React Native app

Tags: java, react-native, environment-variables

While running my react-native app using npx react-native run-android, I am getting this error

```
Configure project :
Directory 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20' (Windows Registry) used for java installations does not exist
Directory 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11' (Windows Registry) used for java installations does not exist
Directory 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8' (Windows Registry) used for java installations does not exist
```

My Java file is not even present in this location. The actual location is "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-17.0.8.7-hotspot". I have verified all the environment variables including path and JAVA_HOME for my java file, but I am still facing the same issue. Please anyone help with this.

I am trying to run the React Native app but am facing an issue related to the Java JDK location.